# Nullability of A non-terminal in parsing tables

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, nullable

Given the following grammar, why is `Z` said to be not nullable

```
X -> Y | a
Y -> c | epsilon
Z -> X Y Z | d
```

Comment: A non-terminal is nullable if an only if it can derive the empty string. It's easy to prove by induction on derivation length that all derivations from `Z` are non-empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it does not contain `epsilon` (null). For example, **Y** is nullable because **Y** can be defined as `epsilon`. As is **X**, because **X** is defined as either **Y** or **a**. If we set **Y** to `epsilon`, then **X** is also `epsilon`.

Interestingly, if **Z** were defined as *only* **X Y**, then there is the possibility for **Z** to also be nullable, because **X** and **Y** can both be set to `epsilon` (as above) thus making **Z** `epsilon`, but because **Z** must end in **Z**, which eventually must end in the terminal **d** (why?), **Z** is not nullable.